# VB.NET Double Control . MouseHover not Performing two action at a time. and Flying Toolbar not in Shape

Tags: position, toolbar, mousehover

I am using two forms. one as a main form and other as a on `Fly toolbar (Windows 7 style)`.
My First problem is :
1. I set Mouserhover to achieve two tasks
   A. To display Form2 
   B To set Opacity = 1
Here is the code:

```
Private Sub form1_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseHover

    form2.RightToLeftLayout = Me.RightToLeftLayout
    form2.Show()
    Me.Opacity = 1
End Sub
```

It's showing form 2 but Opacity is default i.e 0.8 *set in Form Load event) seems as control is passed to form2.
second thing I want to achieve is,
get form2 at the top of form 1.

.